# Return status of Busybox `timeout` command

Tags: shell, busybox, timeout, coreutils, alpine-linux

I'm writing a shell script that's supposed to function on various different distributions, some of which are using `busybox` and some are not.

This script uses the `timeout` command to figure whether a command it executed ran longer than `<time>` or not. In the case of distributions which use the `coreutils` `timeout` this is no problem because when `timeout` had to kill a command it always returns `124`, so that's simple.

My problem is that when I run the same on `Alpine Linux` (which uses busybox ) then the exit status is `0` after timeout had to kill the command, but when I use the `timeout` command from the `busybox` package in Ubuntu it exits with `143`.

Why do the two `timeout` commands, which are both from `busybox`, give me a different return value?

Is there any consistency or rule in that which I can use to determine whether the command has timed out or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpine Linux probably has an earlier version of busybox. A simple solution is to add to your original command another command that has some side effect you can test for, eg writing some output to stdout or a file.

Eg, assuming you want a timeout of 1 for an original command of `sleep 2`,
instead of

```
timeout 1 sleep 2
```

do

```
ok=$(timeout 1 bash -c 'sleep 2; echo ok')
```

and test `$ok` for ok. Obviously, if your command writes to stdout you need to redirect it, eg dup it to fd 3 and redirect to that:

```
exec 3>&1
ok=$(timeout 1 bash -c 'my command >&3; echo ok')
exec 3>&-
```

or do the `echo ok` into a file.